# Append String directly or use StringBuilder

Tags: java, string, stringbuilder

Say I have 3 String variables:

```
String firstName =  "aaa";
String middleName =  "bbb";
String lastName =  "cccc";
```

To append string variables we can use:

```
String fullName = firstName + "-" + middleName + "-" +lastName ;
```

Or we can use StringBuilder:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
builder.append(firstName);
builder.append("-");
builder.append(middleName);
builder.append("-");
builder.append(lastName);
String fullName = builder.toString();
```

When to use StringBulider or when to append it directly?

Comment: Also, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532461/stringbuilder-vs-string-concatenation-in-tostring-in-java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a programmer we should always care about the readability of our code and the first case looks quite readable to me than the second one.

> Now if your question is which one should I choose ?

Than answer is any of them and you should not bother for this.`StringBuilder` only make difference with *loop*, other than that currently both of the cases would be almost same.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way : If you have access to apache common, you could use `StringUtils.join()`.

Next, if all the Strings could be marked as `final`, then use `+` directly as using `+` on `final` Strings (which are compile time constants) is actually a compile-time operation.

If, you don't want to do the 2 things above, then use `StringBuilder` to concatenate strings (Even though `+` on Strings is done using `StringBuilder` internally.

Comment: There's no need to mark the strings as `final`, nor any need for external libraries.  Java compiles string concatenations into `StringBuilder` calls, making them identical.  The only exception is when concatenating a string in a loop or other delayed concatenation operation in which case explicitly using a `StringBuilder` avoids repeated concatenation operations.

Comment: @dimo414 - I know java does that.. You should probably have a look at my last edit..  If there is an external library that already does this, then I think there is no point re-inventing the wheel :)

Comment: Why use an external library when `+` concatenation already does exactly the same thing?

Comment: @dimo414 No, the compile-time concatenation will _only_ happen if they're both final (or both the plan string literals). All of the arguments need to be compile-time constants as defined in JLS 15.28. See this gist: https://gist.github.com/yshavit/67a3658d025eb1510ff6

Comment: @dimo414 - `+` behaves differently for final and non-final strings.

Comment: That's not my point.  `+` concatenation compiles into `StringBuilder` calls, making `+` and `.append()` identical.

Comment: @dimo414 - Well, yes, in case of non-final strings.

Comment: Right.  So why are you advocating for external libraries and explicitly using `StringBuilder`?  For simple (e.g. non-loop) concatenations like OP's case, `+` is exactly what you need.

Comment: @dimo414 - I was merely suggesting that for a larger data set, he has many options.

Comment: Your answer says an external library is the simplest way to concatenate strings, and that (aside from compile-time constants) the right alternative is to use `StringBuilder`.  You say nothing about "larger data sets", nor is OP asking about them.